# control arranger track cubase with MIDI

Tags: midi, cubase, live

When I learn my instrument or for jam I want to command Cubase in a "live" mode like Ableton.

The only solution that I find is that create a arranger track. With this I can "switch" to different build project combinaison.

But I don't find any solution for control this track without mouse.

How I can more approach concept of "live" composition like Ableton with Cubase only ?

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? Sorry I'm having trouble understanding your question in full.

Answer (score 1):

*It is not possible to control a arranger track cubase with MIDI command because the development of Cubase do not design this.*

But it is possible to launch point of arranger track with an Ipad and aplication Cubase Ic Pro which can launch different point of this arranger track on the fly. Also this change not impact to playing (order for change index of arranger track will not skip or stop the play, it will attempt the current index arranger track finish to switch on the index demand)

**For resume : You can't pilot the arranger track with MIDI but with Cubase Ic Pro on appStore.**